# Hyperlinks in yahoo mail redirect user to yahoo home page

Tags: email, hyperlink, html-email, yahoo

I have an email newsletter website that send email to subscribe users every day.
In each email we have some hyperlink that refer to our website.
A few days ago I got problems with Yahoo Mail service:
When user click on hyperlink my website show for a second and then redirect to Yahoo homepage!
I have no any problem with another Mail server such as GMail.
I have no any problem with Yahoo before September 2016.
Simple URL is correct. But complex URL (have Parameters with query string) is my problem and yahoo redirect these hyperlinks to us.yahoo.com.
Whats wrong?

Comment: Webmail clients (including Yahoo) make unannounced changes all the time. Can you provide an example of the "complex URL" you're sending?

Comment: Complex hyperlink example: http://zabanafza.com/WordDetails.aspx?rnd=7049&Email=heidarbozorg@gmail.com&uid=3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I test complex hyperlinks more and more by different parameter value.
The problem is: Send yahoo email address by QueryString.
And this problem is not dependent on technology or language or server or etc.
For example if you send emailAddress@yahoo.com to any website such as bellow you will redirect to us.Yahoo.com:
1- [zabanafza.com/read.aspx?EmailAddress=emailAddress@yahoo.com](http://zabanafza.com/read.aspx?EmailAddress=emailAddress@yahoo.com)
2- http://www.istgah.org/contact-us.php?EmailAddress=emailAddress@yahoo.com

Note: First example is a dot net page that host on Windows server and second one is a php and host on Linux server but result of both is one: **us.Yahoo.com**